# Will Ubuntu TV run on pc's?

Tags: ubuntu-tv

I searched askubuntu.com and Google but unfortunately still am not sure. Do you think that the final Ubuntu TV software will also be available for everyone to be installed on ones pc's? just as OS or a software on top of the normal Ubuntu OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu TV is an Unity variant and it's a proof of concept so everything might change.
The plan is to stick it into the TV, not another box sitting next to it, with lots of cables and another remote. But for now you can install on PC, more info here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuTV/Contributing

And the official page:

http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/tv

Comment: if it's clear,you should choose my answer like the best

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer Yes, if you compile it yourself.

Why is there no official PPA?

The code isn't in a state to run alongside desktop unity, we didn't want to break peoples' desktops we hope to provide a more polished version in a PPA for 12.04

It also uses XBMC as Media Scanner. This is in testing mode currently and is hoped to be included in 12.04 final. I wouldn't expect a polished version as yet.

In the mean time you could use XBMC

http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Installing_XBMC_for_Linux

Comment: Thanks BlueXrider, your answer is very helpful! How can I "choose an answer like the best"? I dont have a login, just use my Name and Email Roberto

Comment: Well, looks like you did. By making choosing to check-mark and upvote.